# Sound bar GUI glitch on MacBook

Tags: big-sur, menu-bar, ui, sound-volume

macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29)

I vigorously swooshed the sound bar in an attempt to turn the music down.

And for some reason, the bar sound is now stuck on the screen as shown in the picture below (Also, if I take a screenshot, the bar doesn't appear in it).

The bar is draggable and functional like the normal bar.

[image]

I tried to do both but to no avail.

```
killall Dock
killall Finder
```

How do I get rid of it without having to restart the computer?

Answer (score 2):

After figuring out what service was responsible for the bar I tried

```
killall ControlCenter
```

And it did the trick